# Подскажите асинхронную либу для работы с http в rust

Tags: postgresql, http, rest, асинхронность, rust

Подскажите асинхронную либу для работы с http rust. Важно чтоб в комплекте с ней шел асинхронный драйвер для postgresql или было возможно применение стороннего драйвера вместе с ней.
Никогда до этого не писал на rust, хочу реализовать на нем задачу небольшого асинхронного rest api сервера.

Comment: И какая связь http и postgres?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, у меня нет опыта в rust, я не знаю как в нем устроена асинхронность. В с++, к примеру, т.к нет одного стандартного event loop'а, для каждой библиотекуи, использующей свой кастомный event loop нужен свой дравйвер, который будет уметь с ним работать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. HTTP - [Hyper](http://hyper.rs). Или более простая в использовании [Reqwest](http://crates.io/crates/reqwest)
2. Для работы с postgresql, например, [bb8](https://github.com/djc/bb8).

Эти крейты опираются на [Tokio](http://tokio.rs)